# Referencing Newtonsoft.Json on Windows Phone 8 requires System.Core v4.0 which isn't avail?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, json.net

I NuGet-added Newtonsoft.Json (6.0.2) to my WP8 app. JObject and JToken are red-squig'd with "Module 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0....' should be referenced."

However, System.Core is incompatible for WP8 projects.

Newtonsoft's website, and multiple pages, state that it supports Windows Phone.

I have other projects, not WP, that already had it package-added. Could it be reusing a wrong version rather than the correct portable one?

Comment: Are you able to compile? Maybe a reopening of the solution will solve your problem with intellisense

Comment: You need to reference the Windows Phone targeted assemblies... not the .Net 4 assmebly.

Comment: Jeff: So, NuGet doesn't do that automatically? I'll find and try those from an explicit download.